# Sinusoidal function

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals

I have a problem. I am confused, I have two function like this:

1. $\sin(t)$
2. $\sin(2\pi t)$

what is the difference between of them and how to calculate period and frequency for second?

Answer (score 1):

We call a signal $f(t)$ periodic with $T>0$ if $f(t) = f(t+T)$ for all $t$. Note that if a function is $T$-periodic, it is also $2T$, $3T$, ... periodic. Therefore, typically, the (fundamental) period is associated with the *smallest* $T>0$ for which $f(t) = f(t+T)$ for all $t$.

The function $\sin(t)$ has a fundamental period of $2\pi$, i.e., $\sin(t) = \sin(t+2\pi)$ for all $t$.

If your argument is scaled, just consider the scaling. Let $2\pi t = s$, then $\sin(2\pi t) = \sin(s)$ is $2\pi$-periodic in $s$, i.e., for every $s$, $\sin(s)$ gives the same value as $\sin(s + 2\pi)$. Since $2\pi t = s$ the period translates to $s + 2\pi = 2\pi t + 2\pi = 2\pi (t+1)$, i.e., the function has a period of 1 for $t$. Let's verify it: $\sin(2\pi (t+1)) = \sin(2\pi t + 2\pi) = \sin(2\pi t)$.

***edit**: In response to the questions you had initially posted in a separate reply (and that got then converted to a comment here):

- $\sin(2\pi t)$ and $\sin(2\pi (t+1))$ are equal

Yes they are.

- the only difference between the two signal is time scaling?

No, there is no difference in time scaling. The two signals are *exactly equal*. If you would plot both of them you would see no difference as the lines would exactly overlap.

- because $\sin(2\pi t)$ take maximum value in $t=0.25$ s but $\sin(2\pi (t+1))$ in $t=−0.75$ s.

That's not correct: $\sin(2\pi t)$ has a maximum at $t=0.25$ and one at $t=-0.75$, just like $\sin(2\pi (t+1))$, it also has a maximum at $t=0.25$ and one at $t=-0.75$. In fact both have maxima at $t=0.25 + k$ for every $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

- There is one more thing. What are the frequency and period(in sec) of $\sin(2\pi t)$.

It's period is 1. It does not have a unit, hence it cannot be expressed in seconds. The time is normalized. If you want to have a sinusoidal with a period of, say T seconds, you need to express it as $\sin(2\pi t/T)$, so that you can insert t in seconds and the units cancel when you divide it by T in seconds. So, for instance $\sin(2\pi t/(1s))$ has a period of 1 second.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood but I am confused ın something . $sin(2πt)$ and $sin(2π(t+1))$ are equal ? the only difference between the two signal is time scaling? because sin(2πt) take maximum value in $t = 0.25$ s but $sin(2π(t+1))$ in $t=-0.75$ s . I don't understand this difference also I don't understand those graphics. There is one more thing. What are the frequency and period(in sec) of $sin(2πt)$?

Comment: Did my edit help clarifying your remaining confusions and questions?